# Lightning Component: doInit is not defined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a Lightning Component PortalHeader

PortalHeader.cmp looks like this:

```
<aura:component controller="currentUserInfoCtrl" description="portalHeader" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="userInfo" type="user"></aura:attribute>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<div id="ui-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
...
```

PortalHeaderController.js:

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.fetchUser");
    ...
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        doInit();
    });
 },
```

and I am getting an error:

> ***doInit** is not defined throws at https://.../AP/s/components/c/**PortalHeader.js**:30:17*

Please note:

1. doInit is right there in the PortalHeaderController.js
2. There is no PortalHeader.js file there is PortalHeaderController.js and PortalHeaderHelper.js

Any idea of what is going on here and why am I getting this error?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This could be a result of Salesforce caching. If this is in a sandbox, go to Setup -> Session Settings and search for a setting named "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" and turn it off. If it's a production instance, just mash Ctrl+Shift+R until it goes away.

Comment: @DrewKennedy No that's not it. it happens on several machines to several users over multiple days. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you share the full file for PortalHeader.js

Comment: This is an example of why chopping out too much code for an example can sometimes obscure the problem. That second `doInit` call wasn't in the original example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was doInit is called within itself.
Trick is to move all the initialization to the Helper file
And then call it once from doInit and again from the event

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.initHelper(component);

        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
              helper.initHelper(component);
        });        
  },
```